# Cloud server migration from Sharefile to Google Workspace (around 400GB)

Tags: migration, cloud, g-suite, citrix

Any advice or program suggestions that I can use to transfer the final amounts of our server data from Citrix Sharefile to Google Workspace? I've transferred the bulk of the data when I was at my previous address on a 1GB line, I have now moved and only have a 70MB line... and at this rate I'll be transferring files till I die. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to migrate server data from Citrix Sharefile to google workspace:

1. Log in to Cloudfuze
2. Add your Citrix sharefile Account
3. Enter your Sharefile Subdomain
4. Enter Admin login credentials
5. Add G Suite to CloudFuze
6. Enter G Suite login credentials
7. Authorize the Cloud Addition Process
8. Verify Whether Cloud Added Successfully
9. Start the Migration
10. Select Source and Destination Cloud Accounts
11. Syncing Migration Pairs
12. Select Users to be Migrated
13. Configure your Migration Preferences
14. Start the Migration
15. Migration Is In Process
16. Migration has been Completed